# Trying to ID a movie I watched in the '90s, featuring a spaceship with a logo showing a star being held between the thumb and index finger of a hand

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I watched a feature-length movie on TV in Romania in the '90s. It was shown on the main TV station in the country, after 10PM, at a time when there was a single national TV station on the air and cable TV hadn't taken off yet. The money was scarce, so I speculate the TV station may have bought cheap direct-to-video productions in bulk. The movie was broadcast in English-language with Romanian subtitles.

Unfortunately, I was only a teenager when I saw this film, so I don't have clear memories of the story or characters. The strongest memory I have is of a spaceship with a logo on its side. The logo was a light human hand delicately holding a star between the thumb and index finger, on a dark background.

The logo was somewhat similar to this, but with a much smaller star, and a few other identical stars above/around the hand:

[image: Logo]

I don't remember the colors, probably because I likely watched the film on a small B&W TV I had in my room.

The ship design I can't really describe. The best I can do is some combination between a [Lambda-class shuttle (*Star Wars*)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lambda-class_T-4a_shuttle) and a [Federation shuttlecraft (*Star Trek*)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_shuttlecraft). It was basically a small vessel with a small crew, its crew entirely shown on screen. I don't remember other technical details about the ship, sorry.

The film might involve an encounter with an alien entity on a planet. I seem to remember some laser-based perimeter security barrier that eventually the mysterious alien entity overruns. However, this might be part of a totally different movie I saw around that time. Sorry, this memory is much fainter.

I believe the spaceship model used in this movie also appeared in another movie I saw on the same channel during the '90s, although the ship had a different logo in the other film. I've asked a separate question about the other film [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/260495/122024).

Comment: In Romania all movies are broadcast in the original language with Romanian subtitles, and the overwhelming majority of all movies are American. The original language of these two was English.

Comment: I've edited this question to make it a bit more distinct from the other one. If you don't mind, I plan to do the same to the other question. If you do mind, let me know, and I won't. You can also roll back this edit to an earlier revision if you prefer, via the [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/260494/revisions).

Comment: @LogicDictates - Thank you. You did not change the meaning of my question and you did a better job of splitting it than I did. Awesome!

Comment: The "laser based perimeter security barrier" sounds like Forbidden Planet. But that wouldn't be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

It looks kind of like the uniform insignia worn by the staff of Tantalus V in the Star Trek episode "Dagger of the Mind".

[image: Dr. Tristan Adams]

Comment: It does, but there weren't any spaceships in that episode, were there? (Aside from the USS Enterprise, obviously.) Since this question is asking about a _spaceship_ with such a logo, I don't see how this can be the correct answer.

Comment: I haven't watched it in a long time; I don't remember if there were any other spaceships in it. Also it's something owlman saw at least 20 years ago. His memory might not be completely reliable either.

Comment: I saw the episode within the past year, and I don't recall any spaceships in it, aside from the Enterprise. I also can't find any mention of any other ships in the [Memory Alpha page for the episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dagger_of_the_Mind_(episode)).

Comment: In regard to the OP's memory perhaps being faulty, that's always a possibility. But in order for your answer to be correct here, the OP would have to mistakenly think the logo was on a spaceship (when it was only on one or more uniforms, and possibly the penal colony on Tantalus V), and also mistakenly think they were watching a feature film with no connection to _Star Trek_ (when they were in fact watching an episode of  _Star Trek: TOS_, with iconic characters like Kirk and Spock). The odds of the OP being _that_ wrong on two separate points seem slim-to-none.

Comment: Dude, whatever, it's just a suggestion, and if OP says it's definitely not it, then fine. I don't know why you're getting so worked up over it though. And, FWIW, if OP didn't remember the details quite right, that doesn't mean his memory is faulty, it just means he's human.

Comment: _"I don't know why you're getting so worked up over it though."_ I'm not worked up over it. I'm just explaining why I think your answer has almost no chance of being correct. _"if OP didn't remember the details quite right, that doesn't mean his memory is faulty, it just means he's human. "_ It would mean _both_ of those things. Everyone remembers things incorrectly at some point, and when they do, it means their memory of that specific thing is faulty.

Comment: These were definitely not Star Trek episodes or movies. I was already exposed to TNG (same station, once a week, Saturday at 5PM), and while I wasn't yet aware of the existence of TOS, I would have definitely recognized the ST universe. On the logo you discovered, nice find but no, that was definitely a star between the fingers, not a bird. It may have been on the crew's uniforms too, in addition to the spaceship.

Answer (score 4):

Is the ship one of these?

[image]

From [this article.](https://worldgeeklynews.com/films/the-reusable-sci-fi-world-of-roger-corman/)

Originally used in [Battle Beyond The Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Stars), and reused along with numerous other props and effects in [Space Raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Raiders_(film)).

I've not seen either film. Can't see any logos in the trailers.  But I'll bet this is it.

Here are the trailers. You can see the reuse of effects even in this short clips.

*Battle Beyond The Stars*

*Space Raiders*

Comment: The blue one is too elongated, and the red one looks much too like a human uterus. The ship I remember did not have prominent nacelles and I do not remember it firing any weapons. That leaves the stubby ship at the bottom which could fit, however I cannot definitely recognize it without the logos.

Comment: Have you watched the trailers? Do they look at all familiar?

Comment: I did now. Definitely not familiar. There were no children and no humanoid aliens, and no action-packed space combat. I think these movies were more thrillers than action movies.