# Trying to ID a movie I watched in the '90s, featuring a spaceship with a logo showing a dark, abstract, rectangular or parallelogram-like design

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I watched a feature-length movie on TV in Romania in the '90s. It was shown on the main TV station in the country, after 10PM, at a time when there was a single national TV station on the air and cable TV hadn't taken off yet. The money was scarce, so I speculate the TV station may have bought cheap direct-to-video productions in bulk. The movie was broadcast in English-language with Romanian subtitles.

Unfortunately, I was only a teenager when I saw this film, so I don't have clear memories of the story or characters. The strongest memory I have is of a spaceship with a logo on its side. The logo was a dark, abstract, rectangular or parallelogram-like design on the light skin of the ship.

The abstract logo in one film could look similar to this:

[image: abstract-logo]

I don't remember the colors, probably because I likely watched the film on a small B&W TV I had in my room.

The ship design I can't really describe. The best I can do is some combination between a [Lambda-class shuttle (*Star Wars*)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lambda-class_T-4a_shuttle) and a [Federation shuttlecraft (*Star Trek*)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_shuttlecraft). It was basically a small vessel with a small crew, its crew entirely shown on screen. I don't remember other technical details about the ship, sorry.

The film might involve an encounter with an alien entity on a planet. I seem to remember some laser-based perimeter security barrier that eventually the mysterious alien entity overruns. However, this might be part of a totally different movie I saw around that time. Sorry, this memory is much fainter.

I believe the spaceship model used in this movie also appeared in another movie I saw on the same channel during the '90s, although the ship had a different logo in the other film. I've asked a separate question about the other film [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/260494/122024).

Comment: have you taken a look at Earth Star Voyager? The ship is a good blend of star wars and star trek stylings. Also take a look at The Shape of Things to Come. here are a couple of links... see if anything looks familiar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ehDDvimoa8     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDFF9sIT6jE

Comment: I could have sworn Firefly had a logo like that somewhere, but I can't find any proof. That would have been early 2000's though.

Comment: Earth Star Voyager's ship is too big, and the ship seems central to the plot, with damage and all. There was no damage to the ship in either of the films I'm looking for. The logos on the uniforms in The Shape of Things to Come are rosette-shaped and I haven't seen them before.

Comment: Some boxy-looking ships with abstract logos: the [skyfighters](https://www.yourprops.com/Visitor-Skyfighter-replica-movie-prop-V-TV-1983-YP38340.html) from the 1983 miniseries *V*, and the ship from the 1988 TV movie *Something Is Out There* which can be seen in a long shot at [44 minutes 36 seconds into the youtube version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvvVei00Weg&t=2676s), and with a closeup showing the writing at [45:03](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvvVei00Weg&t=2703s) (also a flashback showing a character boarding the shuttle to escape the destruction of a larger ship at 1 hr 1 m)

Comment: @Hypnosifl - not what I'm looking for, but you nailed the general styling of the ship.